# Math on analog read wrong result

Tags: analogread, float, mathematics

I'm trying to execute a math of analog read but I get some weird result.. I searched about int and floats but didn't understand..

My code is :

```
#include <SevSeg.h>

SevSeg sevSeg;

int bitsChange = analogRead(A0) ;
float fuel = (923 - bitsChange) * 0.121065375;
sevSeg.setNumber(round(fuel));
```

Assuming bitsChange = 683, so fuel has to be after rounding 29, what I get is 39!!!!

I want to know why I get this result to learn about it..

Comment: rather than assuming, set it and see for yourself...

Comment: I already set it and tried several time with other values, I get each time a wrong result, also tried to declare float and int inside the math but didn't get it solved... That's why I want to understand as I tried several times and failed to get it.

Comment: Try setting the value of `bitsChange` to 683 and printing the value of `fuel` to the serial port. You will probably see that it's exactly what it should be (i.e. the output is 29.06). Maybe there's something wrong with the setup of your seven segment display (i.e. displaced a segment)?

Comment: why are you making an assumption about the value of `analogRead(A0)` ... you have no code that verifies the assumption ... please use `int bitsChange = 683;` instead

Comment: jsotola, yes I did that and I get the correct result (29.06)..but when I let the analog read the input (3.32 Volts) which means 683 bits of the 1023 the result becomes 39!!

Comment: StarCat, I have checked the 7 segment display pins/setup visually and by passing random numbers through setNumber().. it's not the problem..

Comment: If you do `Serial.println(bitsChange)` after setting `int bitsChange = analogRead(A0)` what result do you see on the serial monitor?

Comment: @luker, both Serial.println() & setNumber() show 683 on serial monitor and 7 segment display.. even using (923 - bitsChange) shows the correct result (240), but once I use (*0.121065375) the math is not correct, there is something about this decimal value I cannot understand!!

Comment: Why does the decimal need to be so much precise? Can you try typecasting bitchange  Change to float? And also 923 to 923.0

Comment: @ArduinoFan, not need to be that precise (0.1211 is enough) but also I used 0.121 & getting the same wrong result, I tried also (bitsChange - 923) instead of +923!!! By saying "typecasting" you mean declaring bitsChange as a float? (if you mean that I declared it float and the same error)... I'm going crazy after trying all available solutions.

Comment: When I make the math (923 - bitsChange) * 2.0, the result is 480 which is correct, trying * 1.0, the result is 240, again correct... Once I use * 0.1 the result get wrong!!!! That's why I considered the issue is in the decimal value.